# Excel VBA macro - Issue with copy insert data with formatting

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

I have a spreadsheet where I am inserting rows and copy pasting data (in any row of 1st column) using AutoFill in macro. In macro - Seven-Day, it works fine on other rows but NOT in case if data is in first row and first row has white background. Please guide.
Here is code:

```
Sub Macro7Day()

 If ActiveCell.Column = 1 Then
        Dim numCopies As Long
        numCopies = 6

        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To numCopies
            Rows(ActiveCell.Row + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Next i
        Range("A5:E5").Copy
        Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(numCopies, 4)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(numCopies, 0)), Type:=xlFillDefault 'xlFillCopy
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the problem correctly, can you work towards a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? You can start by having us take a look at only one of the macros before tackling the other.

Comment: @ cybernetic, Modified to one sample

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, your code run well on copying insert data with formatting in any row of 1st column. 
However, as you described it, your code works fine on other rows but NOT in case if data is in first row and first row has white background.
I'm wondering that what does "first row has white background" mean or there is no data in first row ? 
Hope you updates for this.

Thanks,

Yuki